# Is there a difference between "SomeClass<T> where T : SomeOtherClass" and "SomeClass<SomeOtherClass>()"?

Tags: c#, .net, generics

I am learning C# and .net and came across this usage of "where":

```
public class DbContextOptions<TContext> : DbContextOptions where TContext : DbContext
```

Why not simply say

```
public class DbContextOptions<DbContext> : DbContextOptions
```

Are they not equivalent? Or I am totally missing some aspect of this?

regards,

Comment: The second one isn't forcing the generic type to be a `DbContext`, it's just creating a new generic type inside that class called `DbContext`

Comment: `where` represents [generic constraint](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/generics/constraints-on-type-parameters). In the second case `DbContext` will be just a name for generic type parameter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, they are doing different things. The second one isn't doing what you think it is and forcing the generic type to be a `DbContext`. Instead, it's just *naming* the generic type inside that class as `DbContext`. Whether you call it `TContext`, `DbContext` or `Bob` it doesn't make any difference as the name is only used inside the class. But using `DbContext` will clash with the "real" `DbContext` type. So you would still need the generic type constraint.

Comment: And to really drive it home, _this_ is why the name of generic parameters start with `T`, so you don't confuse the parameter with the type.